# Overflow in Lambda function in C++

Tags: c++, algorithm, sorting

I was solving a [question](https://leetcode.com/problems/largest-number/) on leetcode. The question is, Given a list of non-negative integers, arrange them such that they form the largest number. I have got the algorithm to write the comparator function and sort the list based on that. I had written the following,

```
 string largestNumber(vector<int>& nums) {
    auto comp = [&] (string &a, string &b){
       return a+b>=b+a;
    };
    vector<string>s;
    for(auto x:nums)    s.push_back(to_string(x));
    sort(s.begin(),s.end(),comp);
    string ans="";
    for(auto x:s)   ans+=x;
    if(ans[0]=='0') return "0";
    return ans;
}
```

I was getting a Runtime error saying that,

`Line 431: Char 55: runtime error: pointer index expression with base 0xbebebebebebebebe overflowed to 0x7d7d7d7d7d7d7d7c (basic_string.h)`

But I found that in the return statement of lambda function to compare two strings, if I replace '**>=**' by '**>**'  I got the correct answer and it got accepted. Can I know what is wrong with comparing by the sign '**>=**' ? I understand that '**>'** operator compares strings and outputs them in decreasing order but I am curious to know the cause of error.

Comment: `std::sort` needs a *strict weak ordering*. See, for example, [this](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/Compare) for the details.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you open the documentation on [`std::sort`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/sort), you'll see following:

> ```
> template< class RandomIt, class Compare >
> void sort( RandomIt first, RandomIt last, Compare comp );
> ```
>
> ...
>
> #### Type requirements
>
> - `Compare` must meet the requirements of [*Compare*](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/Compare).

And the *Compare* requirements say:

> Establishes [strict weak ordering](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strict_weak_ordering) relation with the following properties
>
> - For all `a`, `comp(a,a)==false`

Your comparator doesn't conform to this requirement, because if you pass two equal strings to it, it'll return `true` rather than `false`.

---

Also note that the first link says that using `T &` as a comparator parameter is not allowed. You should use `const T &`.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I'm still not able to visualize what exactly happens if two strings are equal and how do the comparator function swaps the elements in the original vector if two elements equal. I got this confusion because I have solved another [question](https://leetcode.com/problems/reorder-data-in-log-files/) where I must use '**<='**  in the comparator function, my AC answer for that question was [this](https://pastebin.com/hcG160ie). Can you please explain in deep how comparator function operates with some example or provide any useful reference so that I can understand.

Comment: @AkashTadwai You can use your debugger to look into what exactly `std::sort` does under the hood (the exact algorithm it uses depends on the compiler), but imho it doesn't matter. The manual says the comparator must return `false` for equal parameters, so you need to make sure it does. *"solved another question where I must use '<=' in the comparator function"* From the exercise text alone, I don't see why you'd need `<=` there. In any case, if you solved it using a comparator that returns `true` when given two equal arguments, your solution is incorrect and works only by sheer luck. [1/2]

Comment: There is no guarantee that there will be an error if you supply a wrong comparator. The undefined behavior caused by doing so can have any effect, including it working as intended without any errors. [2/2]

Comment: **_"I don't see why you'd need '<=' there"_**, for that question, I have looked for words in the string after the first space if they are not equal we should compare the words before the first space and see which is lexicographically greater and return true if first is lexicographically greater but if I do like that then also the status is the wrong answer. __" your solution is incorrect and works only by sheer luck"__, I have seen the same way of compare function [here](https://leetcode.com/problems/reorder-data-in-log-files/discuss/654662/c%2B%2B-easy-and-solution).

Comment: Can you describe the algorithm for the same if my comparator function was wrong?

Comment: @AkashTadwai Sorry, I didn't notice the link to your solution in your first comment. What is an "AC answer"? *"algorithm for the same if my comparator function was wrong"* Simply replacing `<=` with `<` in it should give you the same result, but without undefined behavior. But you don't compare the parts before the spaces anywhere in your code, even if the parts after the spaces are equal. *"if I do like that then also the status is the wrong answer."* It's hard to say anything without seeing the code. *"I have seen the same way of compare function here"* That code is also wrong.

Comment: Here's now I would do it: https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/Ncnmhr (just to show the idea, it's probably not optimal).

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. I got clarity that '**<=**' or '**>=**' in compare functions may lead to undefined behavior, and AC- means All correct generally used in programming contests. Yes, I think the tests were weak or the undefined behavior simply produced the correct answer without even comparing the first words,  I got clarity and my code for the correct answer is [this](https://pastebin.com/dwgt8Ya2).